# Disable XDebug Output for Notices

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to figure out how to completely silence XDebug's output in my PHP file. I've already added `xdebug_disable();` to my code, but I'm still getting the following output:

```
<br >
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::
```

...(the error message isn't what I'm concerned about, just stopping XDebug from outputting anything)

The notice isn't preventing my code from completing, and I know what's causing the issue that XDebug is trying to warn me about. But I don't want that extra HTML rendering. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: if you don't show the error message, we could figure out what happened

Comment: I know what's causing the warning, I just didn't show it because that wasn't the issue that I was concerned with. 

I'm trying to figure out how to make XDebug never output any messages, whether there is an error/warning or not.

Comment: The notice messages are coming from PHP not xdebug. Change the PHP [error_reporting — Sets which PHP errors are reported](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: @RyanVincent Thank you!